# How do I add empty spaces in 'SWISH' 'Prolog'?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I am using SWISH and I want to print Hanoi Towers but I dont know how to add empty spaces to html.

```
disk:-html(span(style('background-color:powderblue;')," _ ")),nl, 
      html(span(style('background-color:powderblue;'), " ___ ")),nl,
      html(span(style('background-color:powderblue;'), "_____")).
```

The problem is that towers print in wrong way.

&emsp wont work.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHzXJ.png)

Comment: In HTML, you might want to use `&nbsp;` for a space. For example, `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"` for 3 spaces. Also, don't link a photo. You could have linked to a live SWISH version of your code and it would have been more useful. :p

Comment: I will try with margins.

Comment: It would probably help if you explained what "wrong way" is versus "right way" in how you want the towers to look.